# WPF Scrollviewer starting position strange

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i've got a window with 2 tabs each tab contain a Scrollviewer with same exact properties

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanContentScroll="False">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

the difference now :

First Tab :

the grid row 0 contain a `<WrapPanel>` with couple `<StackPanel>` inside where all controls are

the grid row 1 contain a `<DataGrid>` that fill the rest and has a minimum height

Second Tab :

the grid row 0 contain a `WrapPanel` with couple `<DockPanel>` inside where all controls are

the grid row 1 contain a `<DataGrid>` that fill the rest and has a minimum height

The issue :

when i open the window there is too much control to be viewed all at once so scroll bar or the `<ScrollViewer>` appear and this is perfect. BUT for some awkward reason the second tab the scroll bar is NOT at the top but like a bit more than 3/4 down the window. I wonder if anyone ha that issue before and might know what i forgot there ?

what i've tried :

- named the `<ScrollViewer>` in question and call on the form load `MyScroll.ScrollToTop();` didn't work but i guess it's because the control doesn't exist yet.
- I tried adding the `GotFocus` event to the `<TabItem>` but this baby get triggered every time i also click a control within it. I actually found that funny when i first click a `<ComboBox>` towards the end of the window.

After trying all that i found that starting on top when the `<ScrollViewer>` is fist viewed is what i want and wondering if there is a way to do this or if i am missing something.

Secondly i actually would like the `<ScrollViewer>` to scroll back to top when the person navigate the `<TabItem>` my little go to top bug made me realize that i actually like that.

User will rarely use more than 2 Tabs on that window so insanely perfomant solution not required

Edit :
I've found something. if i scroll back up my problematic tab and then witch o another tab and come back, the scroll return EXACTLY where it was bugged at.

Note that i have no events anywhere just simple bindings on for selected value of combobox and text box. o yeah and datasource for the grid but empty for both tab at this time.

I have 4 windows with the EXACT same formatting and only 1 tab out of 12 do that.

Edit #2 : here the full xaml

```
<syncfusion:ChromelessWindow x:Class="prjSelection.Crating.frmCratingWestManufacturers"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:prjSelection.Crating"   
    Title="West Crating" Height="640" Width="1024"
    UseNativeChrome="True"
    xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"  
    syncfusion:SkinStorage.VisualStyle="Metro" ShowActivated="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="grdOverlay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="99999999" Visibility="Hidden" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="200">
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="White" Opacity="0.8"></Rectangle>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Running Selection" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>
            <syncfusion:SfBusyIndicator AnimationType="Gear" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ViewboxHeight="150" ViewboxWidth="150" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <syncfusion:TabControlExt BorderThickness="0,2,0,0"  Name="tab1"  AllowDrop="False" Background="White" EnableLabelEdit="False" AllowDragDrop="False" CloseButtonType="Hide" DefaultContextMenuItemVisibility="Hidden" SelectOnCreatingNewItem="False" ShowTabItemContextMenu="False" ShowTabListContextMenu="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" TabPanelBackground="White" UseLayoutRounding="False" TabScrollButtonVisibility="Auto" TabVisualStyle="None" TabStripPlacement="Top" TabItemSelectedForeground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <syncfusion:TabItemExt  Header="File" Width="150" IconMargin="0" >
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanContentScroll="False">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <GroupBox Header="File Visual Properties" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="grpFileVisualProperties">
                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <DockPanel Height="25" LastChildFill="True" Width="220" Margin="2,2,0,0">
                                        <Label Content="File Color" Height="25" Name="lblFileColor" />
                                        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=File.Color}" Name="cboFileColor" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=File.SelectedColor, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="120" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                                        <Label />
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </GroupBox>
                            <GroupBox Header="File Relative Properties" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="grpFileRelativeProperties">
                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <DockPanel Height="25" LastChildFill="True" Width="280" Margin="2,2,0,0">
                                        <Label Content="File Type" Height="25" Name="lblFileType" />
                                        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=File.FileType}" Name="cboFileType" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=File.SelectedFileType, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="120" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                                        <Label />
                                    </DockPanel>                                       
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </GroupBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </WrapPanel>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Content="Run Selection" FontSize="20" FontStretch="Normal" Height="46" Name="cmdFileSelection" Padding="0" Width="198.162" Canvas.Left="793.838" Canvas.Top="410" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" />
                        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid AllowGrouping="False" AllowResizingColumns="False" AllowSorting="False" ColumnSizer="Auto" FontSize="13" GroupRowSelectionBrush="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=File.ResultGrid}" Name="grdFileData" NavigationMode="Cell" ShowColumnWhenGrouped="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Canvas.Left="898.447" Canvas.Top="462" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="120" MinWidth="120" />

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </syncfusion:TabItemExt>
        <syncfusion:TabItemExt Header="Box" Width="150" IconMargin="0">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanContentScroll="False">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>   

                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <DockPanel Height="25" Width="375" Margin="2,2,0,0">
                            <Label Content="Height" Name="lblHeight" Height="25" />
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Box.Height}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Box.SelectedHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" Name="cboHeight" Width="200" Height="25" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                            <Label />
                        </DockPanel>                         
                    </WrapPanel>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Content="Run Selection" FontSize="20" FontStretch="Normal" Height="46" Name="cmdBoxSelection" Padding="0" Width="198.162" Canvas.Left="793.838" Canvas.Top="410" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" />
                        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid AllowGrouping="False" AllowResizingColumns="False" AllowSorting="False" ColumnSizer="Auto" FontSize="13" GroupRowSelectionBrush="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Box.ResultGrid}" Name="grdBoxData" NavigationMode="Cell" ShowColumnWhenGrouped="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Canvas.Left="898.447" Canvas.Top="462" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="120" MinWidth="120" />

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </syncfusion:TabItemExt>
    </syncfusion:TabControlExt>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Putting a `RowDefinition Height="*"` inside an infinite container (such as a `ScrollViewer`) makes no sense and will lead to unexpected / erratic behavior. Remove that.

Comment: I just tried `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` and `<RowDefinition Height="200" />` and still not working. just made the window look worse. With * if the wrap panel contained only 2 controls the first row had very small height since it auto fit and the second row took all the rest. so i had more space to view the grid data

Comment: what grid data? please post your full XAML and a screenshot of what you have versus what you need.

Comment: I've cop paste a generated XAML example with this the issue happen in the SECOND scrollviewer with have exact same markup as first.

Comment: dude, remove the scrollviewers, they will only bring you trouble here.

Comment: I need them to be able to see all controls when the windows resize

Comment: you're placing a DataGrid which is a virtualization-enabled control inside an infinite container. That will only bring you trouble. heed my advice, remove the scrollviewer.

Comment: You don't put a `ScrollViewer` and let the UI elements below a DataGrid, forcing the user to scroll down in order to click a button, not in a Windows application. That might be acceptable for web applications, but not Windows applications. Change the `ScrollViewer` to a `DockPanel` or something like that. Plus, having a virtualized control inside an infinite container breaks virtualization and will make your application performance really bad.

Comment: Your scrollviewers may be scrolling due to focus. Is the button the first focusable element?

Comment: OMG, Joel post your comment as answer I'll accept. that was it. dang i didn't know that even when specifying the grid.rows the first focus element don't care about that and just pick first focus-able element it find in the XAML. I know that now i need to generate the wrap Before my last Grid all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to modify the order the XAML was written. WPF focus the first element in the XAML code no matter if it's the last one visually